# Using SVD to plot word vector to measure similarity

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, svd

This is the code I am using to calculate a word co-occurrence matrix for immediate neighbor counts. I found the following code on the net, which uses SVD.

```
 import numpy as np
 la = np.linalg
 words = ['I','like','enjoying','deep','learning','NLP','flying','.']
 ### A Co-occurence matrix which counts how many times the word before and after a particular word appears ( ie, like appears after I 2 times)
 arr = np.array([[0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],[2,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,8],[0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]])
 u, s, v = la.svd(arr, full_matrices=False)
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 for i in xrange(len(words)):
     plt.text(u[i,2], u[i,3], words[i])
```

In the last line of code, the first element of U is used as an x-coordinate and the second element of U is used as a y-coordinate to project the words, to see the similarity. *What is the intuition behind this approach?* Why they are taking the 1st and 2nd elements in each row (each row represents each word) as x and y to represent a word? Please help.

Comment: where is the source of the code, can you post the link?

Comment: @alvas - My friend wrote the code as a part of his project work. But it is working. I cannot make an intuition of how and why they chose U[row,1] and U[row,2] as x and y coordinates

Comment: I had problem to understand it and this helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EokL7E6o1AE&t=22s

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
la = np.linalg
words = ["I", "like", "enjoy", "deep", "learning", "NLP", "flying", "."]
X = np.array([[0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0], [2,0,0,1,0,1,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0], [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]])
U, s, Vh = la.svd(X, full_matrices = False)

#plot
for i in range(len(words)):
    plt.text(U[i,0], U[i,1], words[i])
plt.show()
```

In the plot, pan axes towards left and you will see all the words.

Answer (score 2):

The way SVD is defined, the `s` matrix you obtain from the `la.svd` method is a diagonal matrix containing singular values in descending order. Picking the first 2 columns of `u` ensures that you pick the most important components of your original matrix.

This process is also known as dimensionality reduction. Please read [here](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch11.pdf) (Section 11.3.3) and [here](http://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm).